# Reset/Remove .bash file versions

Tags: bash

New to this and I believe I made duplicates or versions of the .bash_profile. I'd like to know how to make one the priority or delete those that are not active. I think its interfering with my SQL communication.

```
-rw-------   1 noahjones  staff   2342 Sep  3 18:33 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--   1 noahjones  staff    157 Sep  3 18:31 .bash_profile
-rw-------   1 noahjones  staff    201 Sep  3 18:29 .bash_profile.save
-rw-r--r--   1 noahjones  staff     74 Sep  3 16:33 .bash_profile_
drwx------  48 noahjones  staff   1536 Sep  3 18:34 .bash_sessions
-rw-r--r--   1 noahjones  staff    118 Sep  3 15:38 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x   3 noahjones  staff     96 Sep  3 16:01 .bundle
drwxr-xr-x   4 noahjones  staff    128 Sep  3 15:40 .gem
-rw-r--r--   1 noahjones  staff     74 Sep  3 18:33 _bash.profile
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO, This question is not related to Ruby on Rails. Although I may not be the right person in helping you understand where it has to be. With relevance to this question, in my machine, I keep `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Only the `.bashrc` and `/.bash_profile` are relevant. The file `.bash_history` is created automatically to store the history of your commands; the `.bash_profile.save`, `.bash_profile_` and `_bash.profile` must be your backup files -- they are virtually ignored. The `.bundle` and `.gem` are not related to `bash`.

You probably have `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile` misconfigured. The difference between `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` is that the former is only executed once, when you log in, while the latter is run every time you open a new `/bin/bash` shell. Depending on what you need to do with SQL you may want to delete one or the other.